# Transfering objects between images in GIMP

Tags: images, gimp, pixels

When I mark and drag over and object from one picture to another it changes colors (to the other pictures palette) and that makes it look really bad. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the image you are copying to is in RGB color mode - it was most likely in indexed mode with a limited set of colors.